# Error jsRoutes.controllers is undefined when use javascriptRoutes Play framework 2.3

Tags: playframework

I have javascriptRoutes response like this:
http://pastebin.com/7RSA5wZj

in my template, i used:

`var r = jsRoutes.controllers.TblUser.delete(3)`

when i used this, i received an error message:

TypeError: jsRoutes.controllers.TblUser is undefined

How to use jsRoutes correctly?
Sorry for my poor English :)

Answer (score 1):

**1. Add Routes for function**

Add the function delete() to your routes

```
 Controllers.TblUser.delete(String : Example)
```

**2. Create A common function for javacript Routes**

Lets use function JavaScriptRoutes() and add it to your conf/routes

```
 Controllers.CommonController.JavaScriptRoutes()
```

Eg code

```
   public static Result JavascriptRoutes() {
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("JsRoutes",
        routes.javascript.delete(),
        routes.javascript.add()            
    ) );
   }
```

**4.Include the JavacriptRoutes into Scala template as**

```
         <script type="text/javascript" src='@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes()'></script>
```

**5. Use the javascript Routes for ajax call as**

```
     myJsRoutes.controllers.Application.getItem(idToGet).ajax({

     success : function(data) {

      }
    });
```